# Sharepoint 2013 Discussion board Subscription

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, discussion-board

I am new to Sharepoint and have to achieve a requirement.

I would like to give a functionality to User so that he/she can subscribe a Discussion board Post. For this I added custom lookup column 'Category' in Discussion board list with options like 'CAT-1', 'CAT-2' etc. Now whenever new post will be added user need to select Category.

Now my requirement is, there are so many other users who want to Subscribe Category and whenever new Post for particular category is added, he/she can get an Email.

Please suggest how to achieve this.